# Create a output to a command Python

Tags: python, linux, ssh

I have been working on a code that will execute a specific command in python

```
try:
    portNumber = ('\nPlease pick a Port#: ')
    description = str('Please add  port description: ')
    config_commands = ('port set port' +portNumber
    'description' +description)
    #Should become ['port set port' +# description +description]

    print ('Accessing port')  # should be accessing th eport
    output = net_connect.send_command('port set port' [portNumber] [description]) # i 
    returns the output of the config_commands
    print (output) #should show config commands

    print ('Showing New Configuration')
    output = net_connect.send_command_expect('port show status')
    print (output) # print new config

    print ('Saving Configuration...')
    output = net_connect.send_command('configuration save') # returns output of 
    specified command
    print (output)
```

but it keeps failing with
any idea?
It seems to be an issue with combining

```
   [root@localhost ansible]# python show.py
File "show.py", line 37
'description' +description)
```

`output = net_connect.send_command('port set port' [portNumber] description 
   [description]) # returns the output of the config_commands
   TypeError: string indices must be integers, not str`

Comment: Please clarify. If the error occurring on the line `'description' +description)`, or the line `output = net_connect.send_command('port set port' [portNumber] description `? While both lines have their problems, they can't _both_ be raising an error.

Comment: why aren't you just passing `config_commands` to `send_command`?  it looks like that is what you're sort of trying to do

Comment: you probably want to be using the `input` function as well.  maybe go through a tutorial to get a better idea of the basics of python…

Comment: Thanks for the advice. I am going to look into the input function to get a better idea. @SamMason

Comment: @Kevin Both seem to be giving me an error no matter how I write it.

Comment: @Kevin as the code is now 
[root@localhost ansible]# python ciean_show.py
  File "ciean_show.py", line 37
    'description' +description)

Comment: updated to 
try:
        portNumber = raw_input('\nPlease pick a Port#: ')
        description = raw_input('Please add  port description: ')
        config_commands = ('port set port' +portNumber,
        'description' +description)
        #Should become ['port set port' +# description +description]

        print ('Accessing port')  # should be accessing th eport
        output = net_connect.send_command(config_commands) # returns the output of the config_commands
        print (output) #shoudl show config commands

Comment: This is the new error i am getting. 
Please pick a Port#: 4
Please add  port description: Test
Accessing port
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "ciean_show.py", line 41, in <module>
    output = net_connect.send_command(config_commands) # returns the output of the config_commands
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/netmiko/base_connection.py", line 1078, in send_command
    command_string = self.normalize_cmd(command_string)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/netmiko/base_connection.py", line 1185, in normalize_cmd
    command = command.rstrip()

Answer (score 0):

```
config_commands = ('port set port' +portNumber
'description' +description)
```

This is not legal syntax. You cannot combine the variable `portNumber` and the string literal `'description'` without an operator in between them. It doesn't matter that they are on separate lines. Maybe you intended to combine them with "+"?

```
config_commands = ('port set port' +portNumber + 'description' +description)
```

Not that it really matters. You never use the `config_commands` variable, so you may as well delete that line entirely.

Next up,

```
output = net_connect.send_command('port set port' [portNumber] [description])
```

If you're trying to combine `'port set port'` and `portNumber` and `description` into a single string, this is not how you do it. `'port set port' [portNumber]` is effectively equivalent to "return the character in the string `'port set port'` that is at index `portNumber`." But this is only a legal operation if `portNumber` is an integer. Your `portNumber` is not an integer, it is a string: `'\nPlease pick a Port#: '`. If you want to simply combine these values, you could do:

```
output = net_connect.send_command("port set port {} {}".format(portNumber, description))
```

I don't know what the `port` command does, but I'm guessing you don't actually intend to pass `'\nPlease pick a Port#: '` as its first argument. If you want to prompt the user to enter a number and pass that, you should probably be using the `input` function.

```
portNumber = input('\nPlease pick a Port#: ')
```

And likewise for `description`.

Comment: Appreciate the help @kevin, Any way I can give you kudos? That function is working but running into print ("Showing New Configuration")
        ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax

Comment: Kudos usually comes in the form of an upvote or accept. But you should only accept an answer if you feel your problem has been solved. Since you're still getting an error, I don't think you're quite there yet :-)

Comment: You gave me what i need. It works im just an idiot and missed some stuff. Writing up and ill share the results.

Comment: This is what got me rocking and rolling
portNumber = raw_input('Please pick a Port#: ')
        description = raw_input('Please add  port description: ')
        config_commands = ('port set port' +portNumber + 'description' +description)
        #Should become ['port set port' +# description +description]

        print("Accessing" +portNumber)  # should be accessing th eport
        output = net_connect.send_command('port set port {} description "{}"'.format(portNumber, description))